# Alternatives to LIMIT and OFFSET for paging in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-limit

I'm developing a web application and need to page ordered results. I normaly use LIMIT/OFFSET for this purpose.

Which is the best way to page ordered results in Oracle? I've seen some samples using rownum and subqueries. Is that the way? Could you give me a sample for translating this SQL to Oracle:

```
SELECT fieldA,fieldB 
FROM table 
ORDER BY fieldA 
OFFSET 5 LIMIT 14
```

(I'm using Oracle 10g, for what it's worth)

Thanks!

---

**Answer:**
Using the link provided below by karim79, this SQL would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT rownum rnum, a.* 
    FROM(
        SELECT fieldA,fieldB 
        FROM table 
        ORDER BY fieldA 
    ) a 
    WHERE rownum <=5+14
)
WHERE rnum >=5
```

Comment: I think the last line should rather say `WHERE rnum >5` (not `>=`), otherwise you'll get 15 records, skipping only the first four.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will need to use the `rownum` pseudocolumn to limit results. See here:

<strike>http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html</strike>

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Comment: interesting read on how rownum operates : http://blog.lishman.com/2008/03/rownum.html

Comment: No longer available; see instead [2008 capture on Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160706232059/http://blog.lishman.com/2008/03/rownum.html)

Answer (score 34):

As of oracle 12c, you could use the top N queries.

```
SELECT fieldA,fieldB 
FROM table 
ORDER BY fieldA 
OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 14 ROWS ONLY;
```

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php

Comment: Concerning `OFFSET`, please have a look at Markus Winand [Paging Through Results](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page).

Comment: Could you please guide here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499069/apply-offset-and-limit-in-oracle-for-complex-join-queries?

Answer (score 23):

Since you're on 10g, you should be able to simplify the ROWNUM approach using analytic functions

```
SELECT fieldA, 
       fieldB
  FROM (SELECT fieldA,
               fieldB,
               row_number() over (order by fieldA) rnk
          FROM table_name)
 WHERE rnk BETWEEN 5 AND 14;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what i needed :) why oh why does oracle insist on doing things the hard way!

Answer (score 18):

Method-1: For database version Oracle12c or higher

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB 
FROM table 
ORDER BY fieldA 
OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 14 ROWS ONLY
```

Method-2: For database version Oracle11g or lower using analytical function RowNumber()

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB
FROM (
    SELECT fieldA, fieldB,
        row_number() over (order by fieldA) rowRank
    FROM table_name
)
WHERE rowRank BETWEEN 5 AND 14;
```

Method-3: For database version Oracle11g or lower using RowNum

```
SELECT T.* FROM ( 
SELECT T.*, rowNum as rowIndex
FROM (
    SELECT fieldA, fieldB,
    FROM table_name
)T)T
WHERE rowIndex > 0 AND rowIndex <= 20;
```

In some cases, I have found method-3 is faster than method-2 since order by clause is mandatory in method 2. However, if your database version is 12c or higher you must go for method-1.

Comment: Could you please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499069/apply-offset-and-limit-in-oracle-for-complex-join-queries ?