# how to get the second batch and 3rd batch in the same query result in oracle sql + yii framework?

Tags: sql, oracle, yii

let' say i have 20 results in the sql query. if am gonna use the limit in the yii active record, I'll obviously get the first four from the result, but what if i wanna get the 2nd four and then 3rd four in the same query result ? how to query that via sql ?

e.g

```
        $criteria2 = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria2->select = 'USERID, ADID ,ADTYPE, ADTITLE, ADDESC, PAGEVIEW, DISPPUBLISHDATE';
        $criteria2->addCondition("STATUS = 1");
        $criteria2->order = '"t".PAGEVIEW DESC,"t".PUBLISHDATE DESC';
        $criteria2->limit = 4;
        $criteria2->with = array('subcat','adimages');
        $result = $this->findAll($criteria2);
        return $result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry :)

See here, how to paginate with Oracle (Are you use 11g?)
[Alternatives to LIMIT and OFFSET for paging in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912144/alternatives-to-limit-and-offset-for-paging-in-oracle)

Well and in Yii just set offset, OCIConnector will set rownum automaticly for sql

```
    $criteria2 = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria2->select = 'USERID, ADID ,ADTYPE, ADTITLE, ADDESC, PAGEVIEW, DISPPUBLISHDATE';
    $criteria2->addCondition("STATUS = 1");
    $criteria2->order = '"t".PAGEVIEW DESC,"t".PUBLISHDATE DESC';
    $criteria2->limit = 4;
    $criteria2->offset = 0; //4, 8 - COciCommandBuiled applyLimit use it
    $criteria2->with = array('subcat','adimages');
    $result = $this->findAll($criteria2);
    return $result;
```

Comment: what's that "COciCommandBuiled applyLimit use it" ?, do i need to tweak the yii framework class that has something to do with the schema ?

Comment: @sasori, you do not need make any tweaks for get next 4's element - just set offset = 4; (3rd - offset = 8 etc)