# Apply OFFSET and LIMIT in ORACLE for complex Join Queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions, oracle11gr1

I'm using `Oracle 11g` and have a complex join query. In this query I really wanted to apply `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` in order to be get used in `Spring Batch Framework` effectively.

I went through:
[How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering?rq=1) and

[Alternatives to LIMIT and OFFSET for paging in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912144/alternatives-to-limit-and-offset-for-paging-in-oracle)

But things are not very clear to me.

My Query

```
SELECT DEPT.ID rowobjid, DEPT.CREATOR createdby, DEPT.CREATE_DATE createddate, DEPT.UPDATED_BY updatedby, DEPT.LAST_UPDATE_DATE updateddate, 
DEPT.NAME name, DEPT.STATUS status, statusT.DESCR statusdesc, 
REL.ROWID_DEPT1 rowidDEPT1, REL.ROWID_DEPT2 rowidDEPT2, DEPT2.DEPT_FROM_VAL parentcid, DEPT2.NAME parentname 
FROM TEST.DEPT_TABLE DEPT 
LEFT JOIN TEST.STATUS_TABLE statusT ON DEPT.STATUS = statusT.STATUS 
LEFT JOIN TEST.C_REL_DEPT rel ON DEPT.ID=REL.ROWID_DEPT2 
LEFT JOIN TEST.DEPT_TABLE DEPT2 ON REL.ROWID_DEPT1=DEPT2.ID
ORDER BY rowobjid asc;
```

Above Query gives me 10 millions records.

Note: Neither database table has PK, so I would need to use OFFSET and LIMIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Analytic functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()` within a subquery for Oracle `11g` assuming you need to get the rows ranked between 3rd and 8th in order to capture the `OFFSET 3 LIMIT 8` logic within the Oracle DB(*indeed those clauses are included for versions `12c+`*), whenever the result should be grouped by `CREATE_DATE` and ordered by the `ID` of the departments  :

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM (SELECT DEPT.ID rowobjid,
               DEPT.CREATOR createdby,
               DEPT.CREATE_DATE createddate,
               DEPT.UPDATED_BY updatedby,
               DEPT.LAST_UPDATE_DATE updateddate,
               DEPT.NAME name,
               DEPT.STATUS status,
               statusT.DESCR statusdesc,
               REL.ROWID_DEPT1 rowidDEPT1,
               REL.ROWID_DEPT2 rowidDEPT2,
               DEPT2.DEPT_FROM_VAL parentcid,
               DEPT2.NAME parentname,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPT.CREATE_DATE ORDER BY DEPT.ID) AS rn
          FROM TEST.DEPT_TABLE DEPT
          LEFT JOIN TEST.STATUS_TABLE statusT
            ON DEPT.STATUS = statusT.STATUS
          LEFT JOIN TEST.C_REL_DEPT rel
            ON DEPT.ID = REL.ROWID_DEPT2
          LEFT JOIN TEST.DEPT_TABLE DEPT2
            ON REL.ROWID_DEPT1 = DEPT2.ID) q
 WHERE rn BETWEEN 3 AND 8;
```

which returns exactly **6**(8-3+1) rows. If you need to include the ties(the equal values for department identities for each creation date), `ROW_NUMBER()` should be replaced with another window function called `DENSE_RANK()` as all other parts of the query remains the same. **At least 6** records would return in this case.

Comment: How to find MIN and MAX rowCount values here to be used in Partitions of Spring Batch?

Comment: In that case consider to filter out rn = 1, whenever you order by dept.id ascendingly, then you get min, or order by descendingly, then get max value for dept.id and counterparts in return within the main query @JeffCook . (Do you need to learn this?)