# Find MIX and MAX of Row_Number() of Analytic function?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am further taking reference from : [Apply OFFSET and LIMIT in ORACLE for complex Join Queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499069/apply-offset-and-limit-in-oracle-for-complex-join-queries).

How to find out the `MIN` and `MAX` value of `rn` here ?

```
SELECT q.*
FROM (SELECT DEPT.ID rowobjid,
   DEPT.CREATOR createdby,
   DEPT.CREATE_DATE createddate,
   DEPT.UPDATED_BY updatedby,
   DEPT.LAST_UPDATE_DATE updateddate,
   DEPT.NAME name,
   DEPT.STATUS status,
   statusT.DESCR statusdesc,
   REL.ROWID_DEPT1 rowidDEPT1,
   REL.ROWID_DEPT2 rowidDEPT2,
   DEPT2.DEPT_FROM_VAL parentcid,
   DEPT2.NAME parentname,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPT.CREATE_DATE ORDER BY DEPT.ID) AS rn
FROM TEST.DEPT_TABLE DEPT
LEFT JOIN TEST.STATUS_TABLE statusT
ON DEPT.STATUS = statusT.STATUS
LEFT JOIN TEST.C_REL_DEPT rel
ON DEPT.ID = REL.ROWID_DEPT2
LEFT JOIN TEST.DEPT_TABLE DEPT2
ON REL.ROWID_DEPT1 = DEPT2.ID) q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Min value of `rn` will always be 1 and for finding the max. Use max after * as follows:

```
SELECT q.*, max(rn) over () as max_rn, 1 as min_rn
FROM (SELECT 
.......
.......
```

If you want max `rn` within inner query for each partition then you can use `count` analytical function as it will return total number of records within the defined partition(which is nothing but the max `rn` for that partition) as follows:

```
COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY DEPT.CREATE_DATE) AS MAX_RN, 1 AS MIN_RN
```