# SQLSyntaxErrorException ORA-00933 on fetching data using get query

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, jdbc-odbc

```
private static final String  GET_OBJECT_WITH_PREFIX =
    " SELECT OBJECT_KEY, OBJECT_VALUE, LAST_UPDATE_DATE from TEST_TABLE "
        + " where OBJECT_KEY like ? "
        + " order by LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC "
        + " offset ? rows fetch next ? rows only ";

  prefix = prefix + "%";
  pst = conn.prepareStatement(GET_OBJECT_WITH_PREFIX);
  pst.setString(1, prefix);
  pst.setInt(2, offset);
  pst.setInt(3, fetchSize);
  System.out.println("prepared statement: "+pst.toString());
  rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Above code snippet throws below exception

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command
> not properly ended
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:462)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:405)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:931)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:481)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:205)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:548)
> [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:217)
> [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:947)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1283)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1441)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3769)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3823)
> [exec]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1671)
> [exec]     at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:135)

Not sure where it went wrong I tried to print prepared statement as query to understand issue but its not priniting in systemout . Could some one help on the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you connecting to? The offset/fetch syntax wasn't introduced until 12c. Also not sure if the number of rows can be set with bind variable; but that would be a different error.

Comment: Im using 11g. Could you please suggest some alternative to this query in 11g

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternatives to LIMIT and OFFSET for paging in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912144/alternatives-to-limit-and-offset-for-paging-in-oracle)